# React Native - React Navigation Tab Bar - Custom floating action button

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-navigation, floating-action-button

I need some help to use React Native - react navigation library.
It is Tab bar, but the **Upload** button acted as floating action button.

I have try :

```
const click = () => {
  console.log('click');
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>a</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

tabBarOnPress: (tab) => {
  click();
},

// Main Page Navigator
export const Main = TabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeNavigator,
  },
  Explore: {
    screen: ExploreNavigator,
  },
  Upload: {
    screen: UploadMain,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarLabel: 'Upload',
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <View>
          <Icon name="camera" size={26} color={tintColor} />
        </View>
      ),
      tabBarOnPress: (tab) => {
        click();
      },
    }),
  },
}, {
  tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom,
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  backBehavior: 'none',
  swipeEnabled: false,
  lazy: true,
  animationEnabled: false,
  showIcon: true,
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: 'black',
  },
});
```

The Upload button is need to act as floating action button, when it clicked, it already logging, but not rendering the component.
Any workaround to create the floating action button?

I've some tricks like this https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/pull/1335

But, it is only click and dispatch navigation, not doing floating action button

Regards,
Charlie

Answer (score 0):

you should write this code to your component!

-- you can use ‘react-native-tab-navigator' --

```
import TabNavigator from 'react-native-tab-navigator';

...
render(){
        // console.log('TabRouter this.state:',this.state);
        let tabs = [<Home {...this.props}/>,<Chat {...this.props}/>,<Web {...this.props}/>,<User {...this.props}/>];
        let a = this.state.loginData.tabList.map((item,key)=>{
            // console.log('item:',item);
            return(
                <TabNavigator.Item
                    key={key}
                    selected={this.state.selectedTab === item.type}
                    title={item.name}
                    renderIcon={() => <Image source={{uri:item.iconUnselectedUrl}} style={{width:24,height:24,}}/>}
                    renderSelectedIcon={() => <Image source={{uri:item.iconSelectedUrl}} style={{width:24,height:24}} />}
                    badgeText={this.state.tabBadge}
                    onPress={() => this.setState({
                        selectedTab: item.type,
                        tabBadge:0,
                    })}
                >
                    {tabs[key]}
                </TabNavigator.Item>
            )
        });
        // console.log('a:',a);
        return(
            <TabNavigator
                hidesTabTouch={true}
                sceneStyle={{backgroundColor:'#fff'}}>
                {a[0]}
                {a[1]}
                <TouchableOpacity
                    key={'add'}
                    style={{}}
                    renderIcon={() => <View style={{borderRadius:5,backgroundColor:'#46aee3',
                        width:width/5,height:49,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
                        <Text style={{fontSize:49,padding:0,color:'#ffffff',backgroundColor:'rgba(0,0,0,0)'}}>+</Text></View>}
                    onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('SendBlog')}
                />
                {a[2]}
                {a[3]}
            </TabNavigator>
        )
    }
...
```

-- update 2018/01/22 --

I think you should

```
let that;
class UploadMain extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        that = this;
        this.state = {
            change:false,
        };
    }

    changeState = () => {
        this.setState({change:!change});
    };

    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarLabel: 'Upload',
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <View>
          {that.state.change ? <Text>loading...</Text>:<Icon name="camera" size={26} color={tintColor} />}
        </View>
      ),
      tabBarOnPress: () => {
        that.changeState;
      },
    }),

    render(){
        return (
            <View>
                ....
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but what I meant is creating custom Tab bar Component. 
Looks like tabBarComponent can be set to custom compoent.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-navigation version 5.x, you should use `tabBarButton` to modify.
the code detail you can read
https://medium.com/@my.maithi/react-native-navigation-add-custom-button-in-the-middle-of-tabbar-6c390201a2bb

Hope can help you.